# Python: Array search improvement

Tags: python, arrays, list

New to python and I don't fully get a way to improve this better (Even if I know this is not the right way to do this).

I have a list of elements with this format: HIGH-CPU, MID-GPU, HIGH-RAM
There are 27 possible combinations, for each combination I want to add to a pandas dataframe a family combination as a new value.

IE: For HIGH-CPU, MID-GPU, HIGH-RAM will be Family 1.

This is what I have and works, but it should be simpler specially if tomorrow I have to add more possible combinations:

```
def match_list(row):
    fam_list = ""
    tomatch = row
    ##This CSV contains the possible 27 combinations said above.
    result = pd.read_csv("family_list.csv")

    for row in result :
        if tomatch == "HIGH-CPU, MID-GPU, HIGH-RAM":
            fam_list = "Family 1"
        elif tomatch == "HIGH-CPU, MID-GPU, MID-RAM":
            fam_list = "Family 2"           
        elif tomatch == "HIGH-CPU, MID-GPU, LOW-RAM":
            fam_list = "Family 3"         
        elif tomatch == "HIGH-CPU, HIGH-GPU, HIGH-RAM":
            fam_list = "Family 4"            
        elif tomatch == "HIGH-CPU, HIGH-GPU, MID-RAM":
            fam_list = "Family 5"
        elif tomatch == "HIGH-CPU, HIGH-GPU, LOW-RAM":
            fam_list = "Family 6"
        elif tomatch == "HIGH-CPU, LOW-GPU, HIGH-RAM":
            fam_list = "Family 7"
        elif tomatch == "HIGH-CPU, LOW-GPU, MID-RAM":
            fam_list = "Family 8"
        elif tomatch == "HIGH-CPU, LOW-GPU, LOW-RAM":
            fam_list = "Family 9"
        elif tomatch == "MID-CPU, MID-GPU, HIGH-RAM":
            fam_list = "Family 10"
        elif tomatch == "MID-CPU, MID-GPU, MID-RAM":
            fam_list = "Family 11"
        elif tomatch == "MID-CPU, MID-GPU, LOW-RAM":
            fam_list = "Family 12"
        elif tomatch == "MID-CPU, HIGH-GPU, HIGH-RAM":
            fam_list = "Family 13"
        elif tomatch == "MID-CPU, HIGH-GPU, MID-RAM":
            fam_list = "Family 14"
        elif tomatch == "MID-CPU, HIGH-GPU, LOW-RAM":
            fam_list = "Family 15"
        elif tomatch == "MID-CPU, LOW-GPU, HIGH-RAM":
            fam_list = "Family 16"
        elif tomatch == "MID-CPU, LOW-GPU, MID-RAM":
            fam_list = "Family 17"
        elif tomatch == "MID-CPU, LOW-GPU, LOW-RAM":
            fam_list = "Family 18"
        elif tomatch == "LOW-CPU, MID-GPU, HIGH-RAM":
            fam_list = "Family 19"
        elif tomatch == "LOW-CPU, MID-GPU, MID-RAM":
            fam_list = "Family 20"
        elif tomatch == "LOW-CPU, MID-GPU, LOW-RAM":
            fam_list = "Family 21"
        elif tomatch == "LOW-CPU, HIGH-GPU, HIGH-RAM":
            fam_list = "Family 22"
        elif tomatch == "LOW-CPU, HIGH-GPU, MID-RAM":
            fam_list = "Family 23"
        elif tomatch == "LOW-CPU, HIGH-GPU, LOW-RAM":
            fam_list = "Family 24"
        elif tomatch == "LOW-CPU, LOW-GPU, HIGH-RAM":
            fam_list = "Family 25"
        elif tomatch == "LOW-CPU, LOW-GPU, MID-RAM":
            fam_list = "Family 26"
        elif tomatch == "LOW-CPU, LOW-GPU, LOW-RAM":
            fam_list = "Family 27" 
        else:
            fam_list = np.nan

    return fam_list


    df['family_class'] = df['merged_cells'].apply(match_list)
```

So, how can I transform this into a smaller code, that I can actually iterate through and array? I was considering to just see if it's in the array then do this. However how can I make sure that I dont create more than 27 families?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a `dict` mapping test values to families *outside* the function, and use it inside:

```
combo_to_family = {"HIGH-CPU, MID-GPU, HIGH-RAM": "Family 1",
                   "HIGH-CPU, MID-GPU, MID-RAM": "Family 2",
                   ...,
                   "LOW-CPU, LOW-GPU, LOW-RAM": "Family 27",
                   }
```

Inside the function, your loop simplifies to:

```
for row in result :
    fam_list = combo_to_family.get(tomatch, np.nan)
```

(Note: You loop iterates, but only uses the `tomatch` passed as an argument, ignoring the `row` being looped over, not sure what the goal there is, but the logic requires closer examination)

Obviously, typing out the whole `dict` is kind of a pain. If you have the freedom to define the family numberings arbitrarily, you could use `itertools` to generate the `dict` programmatically:

```
 from itertools import product

 combo_to_family = {'{}-CPU, {}-GPU, {}-RAM'.format(c, g, r): 'Family {}'.format(i)
                    for i, (c, g, r) in enumerate(product(('LOW', 'MID', 'HIGH'), repeat=3), 1)}
```

The family numberings won't match what you have, but if the precise numbering isn't important, just distinguishing one from the other, this is an easy way to generate all 27 combinations cleanly.

Comment: That works perfectly fine! I did use itertools.product to get the combination but I didn't have a dict. Actually what you used is a very interesting way. I will have to dig to fully understand how to reach that conclusion myself. Also, there is no need to fix the family numbering so I used your way as well. Now the function is way smaller and easier to maintain. Thanks a lot! You rock.